# It is possible to take a previous row value grouping by two different columns?

Tags: r, data.table

DT:

```
Hteam            Ateam          Season      HT_Points   AT_Points
Grodig          Salzburg        2015/2016       23          29
Rapid Vienna    Altach          2015/2016       38          15
Ried            Austria Vienna  2015/2016       32          30
Sturm Graz      Mattersburg     2015/2016       30          17
Admira          Rapid Vienna    2015/2016       24          27
Altach          Ried            2015/2016       25          10
Austria Vienna  Sturm Graz      2015/2016       29          18
Mattersburg     Grodig          2015/2016       22          12
Salzburg        AC Wolfsberger  2015/2016       45          11
Rapid Vienna    Ried            2016/2017        3           0
Altach          AC Wolfsberger  2016/2017        3           0
Sturm Graz      Salzburg        2016/2017        3           0
St. Polten      Austria Vienna  2016/2017        0           3
Mattersburg     Admira          2016/2017        0           3
Salzburg        AC Wolfsberger  2016/2017        1           1
Ried            Sturm Graz      2016/2017        3           0
Altach          Rapid Vienna    2016/2017        6           0
Austria Vienna  Mattersburg     2016/2017        3           0
```

Desired Output:

```
Hteam            Ateam          Season      HT_Points   AT_Points HT_PointsTOTAL    AT_PointsTOTAL
Grodig          Salzburg        2015/2016       23          29           23 + ?         29 + ?
Rapid Vienna    Altach          2015/2016       38          15           38 + ?         15 + ? 
Ried            Austria Vienna  2015/2016       32          30           32 + ?         30 + ?
Sturm Graz      Mattersburg     2015/2016       30          17           30 + ?         17 + ?
Admira          Rapid Vienna    2015/2016       24          27           24 + ?            65
Altach          Ried            2015/2016       25          10             40              42
Austria Vienna  Sturm Graz      2015/2016       29          18             59              48
Mattersburg     Grodig          2015/2016       22          12             39              35
Salzburg        AC Wolfsberger  2015/2016       45          11             74           11 + ?
Rapid Vienna    Ried            2016/2017        3           0             NA              NA
Altach          AC Wolfsberger  2016/2017        3           0             NA              NA
Sturm Graz      Salzburg        2016/2017        3           0             NA              NA
St. Polten      Austria Vienna  2016/2017        0           3             NA              NA
Mattersburg     Admira          2016/2017        0           3             NA              NA
Salzburg        AC Wolfsberger  2016/2017        1           1              1              NA
Ried            Sturm Graz      2016/2017        3           0              3               3
Altach          Rapid Vienna    2016/2017        6           0             NA               3
Austria Vienna  Mattersburg     2016/2017        3           0              6               0

HT_PointsTOTAL = HT_Points + AT_Points(last game played as Ateam by Hteam)
AT_PointsTOTAL = AT_Points + HT_Points(last game played as Hteam by Ateam)

Note: ? --> It should be a number. 
            It has been put like this since the rows it refers to are not shown.
     NA --> No previous game on that Season by Hteam as Ateam or by Ateam as Hteam.
```

I know what to look for a value from a previous row you can use shift. But in this case I do not know how to do it since the name of the team is the same but in different columns(Hteam & Ateam).

Maybe with shift you can not do what I want to do. The goal is to add the total points of a team. That is, when playing at home, you have to look for the points from the last time that the team played as a visitor and add them(and vice versa).

Maybe the only solution is to use a function to create the new columns. But I don't know how to do it.

It is necessary to use the Season column to group by.

If it is possible to use data.table package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using `data.table` non-equi join using row number to ensure that we only pick from previous rows:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)
DT[, rn := .I]

#calculate home team points first
DT[, HT_PointsTotal := 
    .SD[.SD, .(x.AT_Points + i.HT_Points), on=c("Season"="Season", "Ateam"="Hteam", "rn<rn")]]

#then calculate away team points
DT[, AT_PointsTotal := 
    .SD[.SD, .(x.HT_Points + i.AT_Points), on=c("Season"="Season", "Hteam"="Ateam", "rn<rn")]]
```

---

Adding a `roll` approach when dataset gets larger and there is Cartesian join error due to Hteam appearing multiple times in Ateam column.

```
dummy[, rn := .I]
dummy[, HT_PointsTotal :=
        .SD[.SD, .(x.AT_Points + i.HT_Points), on=c("Season", "Ateam"="Hteam", "rn"), roll=Inf]
    ]

dummy[, AT_PointsTotal :=
        .SD[.SD, .(x.HT_Points + i.AT_Points), on=c("Season", "Ateam"="Hteam", "rn"), roll=Inf]
    ]
```

dummy data (this was time consuming to create and does not reflect reality as well):

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("Hteam,Ateam,Season,HT_Points,AT_Points
Grodig,Salzburg,2015/2016,23,29
Rapid Vienna,Altach,2015/2016,38,15
Ried,Austria Vienna,2015/2016,32,30
Sturm Graz,Mattersburg,2015/2016,30,17
Admira,Rapid Vienna,2015/2016,24,27
Altach,Ried,2015/2016,25,10
Austria Vienna,Sturm Graz,2015/2016,29,18
Mattersburg,Grodig,2015/2016,22,12
Salzburg,AC Wolfsberger,2015/2016,45,11")

numTeams <- DT[,uniqueN(c(Hteam, Ateam))]

firstHalf <- lapply(seq_len(DT[,.N]),
    function(n) data.table(
        Matchday=n*2L-1L,
        Hteam=DT[["Hteam"]],
        Ateam=c(DT[["Ateam"]][-seq_len(n)], DT[["Ateam"]][seq_len(n)]),
        Season=DT[["Season"]],
        HT_Points=DT[["HT_Points"]],
        AT_Points=DT[["AT_Points"]]
    ))

secondHalf <- lapply(seq_len(DT[,.N]),
    function(n) data.table(
        Matchday=n*2L,
        Hteam=DT[["Ateam"]],
        Ateam=c(DT[["Hteam"]][-seq_len(n)], DT[["Hteam"]][seq_len(n)]),
        Season=DT[["Season"]],
        HT_Points=DT[["HT_Points"]],
        AT_Points=DT[["AT_Points"]]
    ))


dummy <- rbindlist(c(firstHalf, secondHalf))[
    Hteam!=Ateam][,
        .SD[1L], by=.(Hteam, Ateam)]
setorder(dummy, Matchday, Hteam)
```

Comment: For the example dataset works perfectly. But for example a full season(my intention is to do it on several seasons) throws me this error.
Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in 1626 rows; more than 360 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again.
allow.cartesian=TRUE logically makes it worse.

Comment: I don't know where I can implementete roll. If you want I can put more lines on the example. But I think that you have the right idea because for the example dataset your answer works perfectly. The only problem(which I don't know how to fix it) is to fix the issue with the key values.

Comment: I 've posted a larger dataset. I hope that people can figure out what I'm trying to achieve,

Comment: Your answer is still working for this larger sample dataset. I do not know why it does not work for a larger dataset with full seasons if the key values ​​are the same. @chinsoon12

Comment: Ok. If you want I can send you by email (I do not know if it is possible) the sample of the dataset that is giving me problems. Anyway, thank you very much. We talk tomorrow. @chinsoon12

Comment: @William88, I posted dummy data and a `roll` approach. I only check a few numbers, can you verify if it achieve your aim?

Comment: .SD[.SD, .(x.AT_Points + i.HT_Points), on=c("Season", "Ateam"="Hteam", "rn"), roll=Inf]
gives me an error--> roll is not implemented for non-equi joins yet.

@chinsoon12

Comment: this is a rolling join not a non-equi join. did u run `dummy[dummy, .(x.AT_Points + i.HT_Points), on=c("Season", "Ateam"="Hteam", "rn"), roll=Inf]` ? what version of data.table r u using?

Comment: This works perfectly. 
`DT$HT_PointsTOTAL <- DT[DT, .(x.AT_Points + i.HT_Points), on=c("Season", "Ateam"="Hteam", "rn"), roll=Inf]`

I also got a solution. Not as good as yours. I copy it on the next comment. @chinsoon12

Comment: `DT1 <- DT[,c("Hteam","Season","HT_Points")]`

`setDT(DT1)`

`DT1[, rn := .I]`

`DT2 <- DT[,c("Ateam","Season","AT_Points")]`

`setDT(DT2)`

`DT2[, rn := .I]`

`DT1[DT2, HT_PointsTotal := AT_Points + HT_Points , on=c("Season"="Season", "Hteam"="Ateam", "rn>rn")]`

`DT2[DT1, AT_PointsTotal := HT_Points + ATpoints , on=c("Season"="Season", "Ateam"="Hteam", "rn>rn")]`

`DTpoints <- merge(DT1,DT2, by=c("rn"))`

`DTpoints <- DTpoints[,c(5,9)]`

`DTpoints <- cbind(DT,DTpoints)`

Comment: doesn't the `rn>rn` cause the Cartesian join error? you might want to double check the result

Comment: No. And don't ask me why.  xD. I also changed the order of the teams. In HT_PointsTotal -> `"Hteam"="Ateam"`  instead of `"Ateam"="Hteam"`
The result is the same for your solution than for mine. But yours is better and cleaner.

@chinsoon12

Comment: Sorry, I need your help again. Following the thread of your previous answer. I wonder if it is possible to roll only the last 5 matches (counting matches playing at home and away, for example 3 at home and 2 at home). My goal is to take average points from the last 5 matches for a team. @chinsoon12

Comment: Roll only last 5 matches and average points of last 5 matches are different questions. You will prob get a faster response if u post these as new questions

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**
Very similar to @chinsoon12 with `data.table` but avoiding using `.SD` so IMO more concise:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)

DT[, rn := .I]

# Join to get away points (i.AT_Points) for Hteam
DT[DT, 
   HT_PointsTOTAL := HT_Points + i.AT_Points,
   on = .(Hteam=Ateam, Season=Season, rn>rn)]  # note rn>rn (using greater than here)

# Join to get home points (i.HT_Points) for Ateam
DT[DT, 
   AT_PointsTOTAL := AT_Points + i.HT_Points,
   on = .(Ateam=Hteam, Season=Season, rn<rn)]  # note nr<rn (using less than here)

DT
```

Resulting in (for your updated sample data):

```
             Hteam          Ateam    Season HT_Points AT_Points rn HT_PointsTOTAL AT_PointsTOTAL
 1:         Grodig       Salzburg 2015/2016        23        29  1             NA             NA
 2:   Rapid Vienna         Altach 2015/2016        38        15  2             NA             NA
 3:           Ried Austria Vienna 2015/2016        32        30  3             NA             NA
 4:     Sturm Graz    Mattersburg 2015/2016        30        17  4             NA             NA
 5:         Admira   Rapid Vienna 2015/2016        24        27  5             NA             65
 6:         Altach           Ried 2015/2016        25        10  6             40             42
 7: Austria Vienna     Sturm Graz 2015/2016        29        18  7             59             48
 8:    Mattersburg         Grodig 2015/2016        22        12  8             39             35
 9:       Salzburg AC Wolfsberger 2015/2016        45        11  9             74             NA
10:   Rapid Vienna           Ried 2016/2017         3         0 10             NA             NA
11:         Altach AC Wolfsberger 2016/2017         3         0 11             NA             NA
12:     Sturm Graz       Salzburg 2016/2017         3         0 12             NA             NA
13:     St. Polten Austria Vienna 2016/2017         0         3 13             NA             NA
14:    Mattersburg         Admira 2016/2017         0         3 14             NA             NA
15:       Salzburg AC Wolfsberger 2016/2017         1         1 15              1             NA
16:           Ried     Sturm Graz 2016/2017         3         0 16              3              3
17:         Altach   Rapid Vienna 2016/2017         6         0 17             NA              3
18: Austria Vienna    Mattersburg 2016/2017         3         0 18              6              0
```

If you like you can remove the rn column when you're done:

```
DT$rn <- NULL
```

Comment: I'm sorry but that does not work as I expect. I have put a new sample dataset in case it could be clearer. In the answer of chinsoon12 if it works but for a larger dataset it has problems when doing the join.

Comment: Ah, I see you have also added a criteria "NA --> No previous game on that Season by Hteam as Ateam or by Ateam as Hteam." I'll amend my answer to handle that.

Comment: Updated to match desired output for your new sample data set.